# How to return a JSON response in errorHandler Middleware in NodeJS using Express?

Tags: node.js, express

How to return a JSON response from errorHandler Middleware in NodeJS using Express. My code is:

**UserController.js**

```
const UserService = require("../services/UserService");

exports.createUser = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        throw new Error("Error from UserController");
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
};
```

**index.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const conectarDB = require("./config/DBConfig");
const cors = require("cors");

//Crear el servidor
const app = express();

//Conectar a la BD
conectarDB();

//Habilitar cors
app.use(cors());

//Habilitar express.json
app.use(express.json({ extended: true }));

//Puerto de la app
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;

//Rutas
app.use("/api/user", require("./routes/UserRoute"));

//ErrorHandler middleware 
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
});

//Arrancar el app
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`El servidor está funcionando en el puerto ${PORT}`);
});
```

**UserRoute.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const UserController = require("../controllers/UserController");

router.post("/", UserController.createUser);

module.exports = router;
```

I would like to get a JSON response from my errorHandler middleware, like that:

```
{
  error: "Error from UserController"
}
```

My current code doesn't work. it doesn't return any JSON response.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Did you handle the error properly in the router earlier?

For example, as below.

```js
router.get('/user', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    
    .... // some logics...

  } catch (err) {
    // you should call 'next' for throwing error to your error handler.
    next(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, but I wouldn't like to repeat that code for each route definition. Is there any way to improve that code?.

Comment: @OmarMurcia, Essentially, it seems right to deal with it in the same way as above. If you want a kind of shortcut, there are some libraries to help you. like '[express-async-errors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-async-errors)'.

Answer (score 2):

As @Won Gyo Seo mentions you need to use `next` to call the next middlewere in the stack, if you don't you'll never reach your error handler. That means putting catch and next on every route. I understand if you don't want to do that.

One way would be to make a helper function

```
bindAndCatch (fn) {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    fn(req, res, next)
      .then(res.json.bind(res))
      .catch(next)
  }
```

You can now do

```
router.get('/user', bindAndCatch((req) => {
  return createUser(req.id)
}))
```

It will return the promise and catch the error,  call the next middlewere and pass the error to it.